# How to determine the particular key sequence dialed from the .wav file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

Namaste! I'm working on project related to dial tones and the key pressed based on the wave file. I'm able to read and plot the same in both time and frequency domain. But I don't know how to detect the key pressed based on the tone.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your looking for DTMF tones. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/dft-estimation-with-the-goertzel-algorithm.html should help

Comment: @exussum I have tried this. The thing is I have the dial tones, and I need to find the numbers. The opposite of the example in the link.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of that link. First part is generating. Next part is finding the numbers.